# How to make it so only certain people can message?

Tags: python

```
if message.content.startswith("$s") and message.author == "Talon#1509":
    message.channel = client.get_channel(808825410669903984)
    print(message.author)
    print(message.channel)
  
    mess = " ".join(message.content.split(" ")[1:])
    await message.channel.send(mess)
```

When I, Talon#1509, posts a message starting with $s, it does not send a message. Is there anyway to fix this issue?

Comment: `mess = message.content.replace("$s", "")` is what I think you want instead of `" ".join(message.content.split(" ")[1:])`

Comment: You may need to compare against `str(message.author)` or `message.author.name` (both of which return the name in the format you want), as `message.author` by itself is not a string so it's not going to pass your check.